# C++ debugging segfault, runs fine without debugging

Tags: c++, list, debugging

I am working with a tree-structure.

All nodes in the tree are kept in a list, the children of each node are kept in a list of TreeNode pointers within the TreeNode object.

This should recursively erase a subtree starting from a given node.

It erases the TreeNode-object itself from the "nodes" list, and then the pointer in the children-list.

It works fine, however when I use the built in debugger in the IDE, it segfaults the first time destroySubtree is called with (*i). It does not segfault when I run the program normally, and does what it should. 
But this means I can't use the debugger for anything else in the program. 
At first I thought it had something to do with how I do the actual erasing, but it segfaults at the FIRST recursive call of destroySubtree - before it does any erasing...

```
void Tree::destroySubtree(TreeNode* node)
{
    if(node->children.size() == 0)
        return;

    list<TreeNode*>::iterator i;

    for(i = node->children.begin(); i != node->children.end(); i++)
    {
        destroySubtree((*i)); //segfaults here, only when debugging

        list<TreeNode>::iterator j;
        for(j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); j++)
        {
           if((j)->nId == (*i)->nId)
           {
               nodes.erase(j);
               break;
           }
        }
        node->children.erase(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can avoid the segfault?

It fails at, stl_list.h:768 if that helps?

Comment: `node->children.erase(i); i--;` doesn't look right. Maybe `i = node->children.erase(i);`

Comment: If you want to erase via an iterator, do it in reverse order. I'm lazy - I just keep erasing the first child until there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `node->children->erase(i)`, `i` is an invalid iterator. Any operations on the it after that is cause of undefined behavior. What you need to use is:

```
 i = node->children.erase(i);
```

and remove the code for incrementing and decrementing the iterator.

```
for(i = node->children.begin(); i != node->children.end(); /* ++i Don't need this*/ )
{
    destroySubtree((*i)); //segfaults here, only when debugging

    list<TreeNode>::iterator j;
    for(j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); j++)
    {
       if((j)->nId == (*i)->nId)
       {
           nodes.erase(j);
           break;
       }
    }
    i = node->children.erase(i);
    // i--; Don't need this.
}
```